# Is it a good idea to test the robustness of a Neural Network on a linear relation?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, regression, overfitting, linear-models

Just to give you more context, I'm currently working on a finance project relying on neural network. I'm principally using Neural Network to achieve regression task. So my neural network aims to predict a non-linear convex relationship between input and output.

```
model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(n_units, activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1))
model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adamax(learning_rate=learning_rate))
```

My supervisor told me to test the performance of my neural network on a linear relationship. ( I give as inputs the same regressors and as an output something which is a linear function of the regressors ). I don't really see how this could be pertinent, especially that my neural network is more likely to overfit my linear relation. Even if I perform a hyperparameters optimization to make my neural net works well on the linear relationship, I'm not sure it will work fine when I use it again for the non-linear.
I'm really getting lost. Can anyone please advise me on a way I could make my neural net works well on both tasks? ( Or is it utopic to expect that from the neural net ).
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. Clearly this would be a terrible way to evaluate the model. The proper way to evaluate would be to design a method which is as close as possible to the target task for which the model is intended. This usually involves collecting some real dataset, apply the model and test whether the predictions of the model correspond to what actually happens.

Comment: Thank you @Erwan , I got your point, I should compare with other models rather than just fine-tuning everytime to make it work on a particular relation. Lot of thanks !